# First line in reledmac verse environment breaking apart

Tags: reledmac

This is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}
    \usepackage{reledpar}
    \setstanzaindents{12,0}
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
                \beginnumbering
\pstart[\section*{A poem}]
\pend
\setline{1}
                    \begin{astanza}
Line 1&
Line 2\&
                    \end{astanza}
                \endnumbering
            \end{Leftside}

            \begin{Rightside}
                    \beginnumbering
\pstart[\section*{Translation}]
\pend
                        \firstlinenum{1000000}
                        \pstart
Translation here...
                        \pend
                    \endnumbering
            \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
    \Pages      
\end{document}
```

What I get in the pdf on the left page is this:

```
L
ine 1
Line 2
```

Obviously, I am doing something wrong. Any help?

Comment: I didn't get this result. Cf this file. https://framadrop.org/r/eAH1xv5nou#zIXvAQAquRhI9uDUyT6BalQEhYiEBtFuVHxb1iASQXc= Are you up to date?

Comment: Yes, I made a complete installation (MikTex) a few weeks ago. After your comment I also updated reledmac and reledpar from CTAN to the current version. The result is the same as before.

Comment: Here is [the log file](https://framadrop.org/r/Nj6BMX7fml#01G+VYBoG33glR39jEhtc1uM7DqQ11PiGTqEjGgCzP0=).

Comment: You are right. There is a problem. I am looking on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a bug since v. 2.18.0 of reledpar (I forgotten that I was not in my computer yesterday). The version 2.19.5 of reledpar, which I will send now on CTAN and will be available in MikTeX soon, correct it.