# First line in each astanza broken and title missing - reledmac / reledpar

Tags: double-sided, reledmac, reledpar, parallel-texts

**TL;DR Why is the first line of every stanza broken after the first character when using astanza from the reledpar / reledmac package? And why is the title missing?**

I am currently creating a Latex document in a twoside class which contains a bilingual text: On the left side (the left page) there is always a latin text and on the right side (the right page) there is the german translation. For this I am using reledpar. I have stanzas (astanza) on the left side and the translation on the right side and I always let a headline / title preceed the actual stanza / translation.

I add the title as a parameter to the astanza environment which is therefore passed on to the pstart, because astanza is just a special wrapper of pstart / pend.

Now my problem is that when I compile my MWE locally the first line of every astanza is broken after the first character. Also the title of every astanza is missing. See the following screenshot or PDF.
[image: Broken line and no title astanza]
[Broken line and no title astanza PDF](https://mega.nz/#!875yXZqT!sWeaue2owM45Kfzclc8nrjB6ECcfEDgKZzgy2EOb_tk)
I tested this with my local LaTeX installation (MikTex) and TexMaker as well as TexStudio. The reledmac version I have installed locally is 2.24.0 from the 18th of August 2017. I also tried compiling this MWE on sharelatex with all available compilers and always have the same result.

If I use overleaf to compile this, it works totally fine. See the following screenshot or PDF.
[image: Wroking astanza with headline on overleaf]
[Wroking astanza with headline on overleaf PDF](https://mega.nz/#!V7xVURpI!gIiq5YPkc2um8Jyq-NzmtQfC-yk0kHywJPFxmOUDPCw)
Now my problem is, that overleaf is really slow and very hard to debug (my output document has around 100 pages). Therefore I can not go on with working only on overleaf. I really do not understand why it is **only working on overleaf**.

This is my MWE. Every help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}

% Set stanza indentation
\setstanzaindents{0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}

\begin{document}
    \large
        \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
                \begin{astanza}%[\centering\textbf{1. POEM1 dial}]
                    verse  verse verse 1!&  
                    verse verse verse 2!&   
                    verse verse verse 3!&   
                    verse  verse verse 1!&  
                    verse verse verse 2!&   
                    verse verse verse 3!&   
                    verse verse verse 88!\&  
                \end{astanza}
            \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \linenummargin{left}
            \begin{astanza}%[\centering\textbf{1. POEM3 dial}]
                This is a translation paragraph\&[\vskip\baselineskip]       
            \end{astanza}
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the lastet version of reledmac/reledpar. This bug was corrected in v2.19.5 of reledpar.

Comment: ps: see post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385520/7712

Comment: Thank you very much Maïeul! In that version the problem does not occur anymore.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the helpful comment from Maïeul and having a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation) I found out that there were two different versions of reledmac installed by MikTex. The correct version (2.24.0) was installed via the **MikTex Package Manager (Admin)**, but this was not the version that was used by Latex. I also had to use the **MikTex Package Manager** (without the --admin flag) to update the package for the currently logged in user.
After doing this the problem was solved.